# Given the model/view/projection transformation matrix, how do I compute the normal matrix without using deprecated features in GLSL 1.2?

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

I know that the normal transformation matrix is the inverse of the transpose of the model/view/projection matrix, but it looks like "[`inverse`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/inverse.xml)" was only added in GLSL 1.4 and I can't find a "`transpose`".  Do I have to just copy and paste a bunch of math into my GLSL? (If so, is there a nice authoritative open-source place I can copy from?)

To be clear, what I'm asking is "How do I calculate `gl_NormalMatrix` without using deprecated APIs"?

Comment: BTW, there's not a whole lot of point in avoiding "deprecated APIs" if you're confined to GL 2.1.

Comment: Isn't it easier to forward-port to newer versions of OpenGL and OpenGL ES if you stick to stuff that works on a core profile?

Answer (score 3):

This is normally handled by computing the transpose of the inverse of the modelview matrix

```
N = (M^-1)^T
```

on the CPU, then uploading the matrix just like uploading any other matrix.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I ended up doing.  Specifically, I ended up doing this in Python, using NumPy, where it's `transpose(M[:3,:3]).I`, but I suspect that is a bit of a pain to do in C.

Answer (score 0):

just to clarify there's also [transpose](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/transpose.xml) and if you don't do any scale the normal matrix is the 3x3 submatrix, in glsl you can do

```
normal = mat3(model_matrix) * v_normal;
```

Comment: This should be avoided, as it cannot handle *all* cases. While it's true that you're mentioning this limitation explicitly, it's unlikely to be a realistic expectation as programs keep getting modified... and suddenly, someone scales something and will go off looking for problems in the scaling code, when it's in fact, not there... and since there's no step-by-step debugger for shaders in the GPU, this is just asking for trouble.